# How to set style on the first item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, styles, navigation-drawer, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to set styles on my NavigationDrawer's RecyclerView. I configured the style in the onClick event but it can't set a style into the 1st item when my app loads.

I'm trying this:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Informacion current = data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.title);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);

        Log.d("onBind", "Position = " + position);
        if(position == 0){
            Log.d("onBind", "PAINT THE FIRST ELEMENT!");
            holder.title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4CAF50"));
        }

        if (!selected.contains(position)){
            // view not selected
            holder.title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#727272"));
        }
        else {
            // view is selected
            holder.title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4CAF50"));
        }
    }
```

After i click on an item, it works fine. Just the first load its the issue.

Thanks for your time. Regards.

Comment: Looks to me like your if-else will simply override the logic applied by the `position == 0` condition. What exactly are you trying to achieve with the first item? Should it look differently from all other items, or is it also selectable?

Comment: It should look with a diferent font color (selected one) but it doesn't, it only change when i click on another and the click on it.